# Error installing MySQL Workbench on CentOS 9 Stream

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mysql-workbench

I am running CentOS 9. I installed MySQL by running the command dnf install mysql-server

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench. I downloaded the file from the official repo. When I try to install, I am getting the below error message: -

```
[root@lemon Downloads]# dnf install mysql-workbench-community-8.0.29-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:45 ago on Saturday 21 May 2022 05:05:23 PM.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libproj.so.22()(64bit) needed by mysql-workbench-community-8.0.29-1.fc35.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpython3.10.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by mysql-workbench-community-8.0.29-1.fc35.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@lemon Downloads]#
```

Below are the list of packages related to Python that are installed -

```
[root@lemon Downloads]# dnf list installed | grep python
libcap-ng-python3.x86_64                         0.8.2-7.el9                      @AppStream
libpeas-loader-python3.x86_64                    1.30.0-4.el9                     @AppStream
policycoreutils-python-utils.noarch              3.3-5.el9                        @AppStream
python-unversioned-command.noarch                3.9.10-2.el9                     @AppStream
python3.x86_64                                   3.9.10-2.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-PyMySQL.noarch                           0.10.1-6.el9                     @appstream
python3-audit.x86_64                             3.0.7-102.el9                    @AppStream
python3-brlapi.x86_64                            0.8.2-4.el9                      @AppStream
python3-cairo.x86_64                             1.20.0-4.el9                     @AppStream
python3-cffi.x86_64                              1.14.5-5.el9                     @appstream
python3-chardet.noarch                           4.0.0-5.el9                      @anaconda 
python3-cryptography.x86_64                      36.0.1-2.el9                     @appstream
python3-cups.x86_64                              2.0.1-10.el9                     @AppStream
python3-dasbus.noarch                            1.4-5.el9                        @AppStream
python3-dateutil.noarch                          1:2.8.1-6.el9                    @anaconda 
python3-dbus.x86_64                              1.2.18-2.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-devel.x86_64                             3.9.10-2.el9                     @appstream
python3-dnf.noarch                               4.12.0-1.el9                     @baseos   
python3-dnf-plugins-core.noarch                  4.1.0-1.el9                      @baseos   
python3-firewall.noarch                          1.0.0-2.el9                      @anaconda 
python3-gobject.x86_64                           3.40.1-5.el9                     @AppStream
python3-gobject-base.x86_64                      3.40.1-5.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-gpg.x86_64                               1.15.1-6.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-hawkey.x86_64                            0.67.0-1.el9                     @baseos   
python3-idna.noarch                              2.10-7.el9                       @anaconda 
python3-libcomps.x86_64                          0.1.18-1.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-libdnf.x86_64                            0.67.0-1.el9                     @baseos   
python3-libevdev.noarch                          0.9-4.el9                        @appstream
python3-libs.x86_64                              3.9.10-2.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-libselinux.x86_64                        3.3-2.el9                        @AppStream
python3-libsemanage.x86_64                       3.3-3.el9                        @appstream
python3-libstoragemgmt.x86_64                    1.9.3-1.el9                      @AppStream
python3-libxml2.x86_64                           2.9.13-1.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-louis.noarch                             3.16.1-4.el9                     @AppStream
python3-lxml.x86_64                              4.6.5-2.el9                      @AppStream
python3-nftables.x86_64                          1:0.9.8-12.el9                   @anaconda 
python3-pexpect.noarch                           4.8.0-7.el9                      @anaconda 
python3-pip.noarch                               21.2.3-6.el9                     @appstream
python3-pip-wheel.noarch                         21.2.3-6.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-ply.noarch                               3.11-14.el9                      @appstream
python3-policycoreutils.noarch                   3.3-5.el9                        @AppStream
python3-psutil.x86_64                            5.8.0-12.el9                     @AppStream
python3-ptyprocess.noarch                        0.6.0-12.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-pyatspi.noarch                           2.38.1-3.el9                     @AppStream
python3-pycparser.noarch                         2.20-6.el9                       @appstream
python3-pycurl.x86_64                            7.43.0.6-8.el9                   @AppStream
python3-pysocks.noarch                           1.7.1-12.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-requests.noarch                          2.25.1-6.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-rpm.x86_64                               4.16.1.3-11.el9                  @anaconda 
python3-setools.x86_64                           4.4.0-4.el9                      @anaconda 
python3-setuptools.noarch                        53.0.0-10.el9                    @anaconda 
python3-setuptools-wheel.noarch                  53.0.0-10.el9                    @anaconda 
python3-six.noarch                               1.15.0-9.el9                     @anaconda 
python3-speechd.x86_64                           0.10.2-4.el9                     @AppStream
python3-systemd.x86_64                           234-18.el9                       @anaconda 
python3-tracer.noarch                            0.7.5-4.el9                      @AppStream
python3-urllib3.noarch                           1.26.5-3.el9                     @anaconda
```

How to resolve the package dependency issue? Please help... thanks

Comment: There isn't a RHEL/OL/Centos9 release. So perhaps try a Linux - generic tarball.

Comment: Okay i now installed the generic binary. Still I am unable to install the workbench. Question content updated. Thanks